How to properly open NARR Grib1 file in Python using MetPy
I am trying to properly open and read a GRIB1 NARR data file as obtained from https://thredds.rda.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/files/g/d608000/3HRLY/catalog.html.
I have tried using xr.open_dataset with the engine set to cfgrib.  I have tried using several other methods within python, from both the metpy and xarray packages.
There are 248 layers (variables) in the these grib files (R's terra package easily finds them), but no method in Python works.  Isn't there a package that will work in Python for working with these files?  There must be, but I can't seem to find it.  I need to use Python because I want to use the metpy package to calculate advection, vorticity, and other values with the metpy package.  And, I really don't want to redownload everything as netcdf files (if that's possible).  Thank you.
